# Click event on dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add an event handler to a dynamically generated list. I need to prevent the default action on the list item, and just console log "clicked". An example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```js
$("#make-list").click(function() {
    var mainList = document.getElementById("the-list");
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        mainList.innerHTML += "<li class='list-item'><a class='the-list__link' href='https://example.com'>Click ME!</a></li>"
    };
})

$(".the-list__link").on("click", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="make-list">MAKE LIST</button>
<ul id="the-list"></ul>
```

These answers:

- [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)
- [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Explain that due to how the `.click()` event is delegated, to use `.on()` method. I'm doing that. Why is it not working?

Comment: Just move the event handler in the same method *after* creating the list.

Comment: Maybe you should read those 2 question/answer again, the way you are binding click is not delegated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not actually delegating the click (should be `$("#the-list").on("click", '.the-list__link'`)
2. You forgot to pass the event to the function that does `e.preventDefault();`

```js
$("#make-list").click(function() {
  var mainList = document.getElementById("the-list");
  for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    mainList.innerHTML += "<li class='list-item'><a class='the-list__link' href='https://example.com'>Click ME!</a></li>"
  };
})

$("#the-list").on("click", '.the-list__link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="make-list">MAKE LIST</button>
<ul id="the-list"></ul>
```

Comment: I read the answers I posted closer - I missed that you needed to target the parent. I thought `.on()` would just target the links with the way I was doing it.

Answer (score 1):

delegate from existing element like body or the-list.
example

```
$("#the-list").on("click", ".the-list__link", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
});
```